# Compiling C++ with cygwin doesn't search provided include paths

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, cygwin

I am working within a tree that compiles fine on any Unix machine I throw it at, but Cygwin is being difficult and I'm not really sure where to start. I have the following directory structure:

```
buildwin/
|-- main.cpp
|-- other project files
|-- include/
    |-- tclap
        |-- CmdLine.h
        |-- other files (including CmdLine.cpp)
    |-- eigen
        |-- (appropriate files)
    |-- rapidxml
        |-- (appropriate files)
```

When I try to compile this, I get the following error from g++:

```
$ g++ main.cpp -lglut32 -lglu32 -lopengl32 -Iinclude/eigen -Iinclude/rapidxml -Iinclude/tclap
main.cpp:6:27: fatal error: tclap/CmdLine.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I know it's finding the other libraries (`eigen` and `rapidxml`) fine because if I remove the respective include flags, it throws an error saying that it can't find `eigen` or what have you.

The include statement in question is:

```
// snip
#include <Eigen/StdVector>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include <tclap/CmdLine.h>
// snip
```

Ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're specifying `-Iinclude/tclap`, then include `tclap/CmdLine.h`, so the compiler goes hunting for `include/tclap/tclap/CmdLine.h`.

Either use `-Iinclude`, or include `CmdLine.h` without the path.

Comment: That's the one! I initially added them all individually because the structure of the `eigen/` and `rapidxml/` directories required it (the actual root of the eigen library is at `include/eigen/eigen`). Including `include/eigen`, `include/rapidxml` and `include` worked, though. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Does using `-Iinclude` work? You probably don't need to be explicitly adding the subdirs of `include` because you refer to them in the names in the `#include` statements.

Comment: That was it! Upvoted, but the other comment beat you by a minute. Thanks!